# How to display .ptm file in my website without using JAVA

Tags: java, php, image-processing, webview

I build a logic(at local machine) which rendered *Polynomial Texture Map* (*.ptm*) on my php website. This is done by JAVA applet and it's working fine.

PHP:

```
<applet archive="PATHTOJARFILE/envlib.jar" height="600" width="700">
    <param name="ptmfile" value="PATHTO_PTM_FILE/xxx.ptm">
    <param name="bg_red" value="100">
    <param name="bg_green" value="100">
    <param name="bg_blue" value="100">
    <param name="pw" value="700">
    <param name="ph" value="600">
</applet>
```

But there is the problem when JAVA is not installed on viewer machine because I have used *JAVA(.jar)* file as logic which means JAVA installation is must on viewer.

Is there any other way to accomplish *.ptm* file display without *JAVA* in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file.
Find a ptm file converter to generate an image of the file to include in your page and add a link to the original file + jar for those with Java who want to see the original file

Comment: The solution which you are providing is manual process and I have already incorporated the changes. The solution I require is for "rendering .ptm file" WITHOUT Java.

Comment: I was meaning use php to automatically convert as I cant see a cross  platform java free way to display a ptm